# Is it safe to operate a kitchen stove without the original insulation installed?

Tags: kitchens, appliances

My rental house has an electric stove that has had a nest of mice living in the insulation.  We removed the insulation to clean. Is it safe to use without replacing it?

Comment: Insulation is typically a replacement part just like other parts of the stove, so you may be able to just purchase a new insulation blanket for it. For [example](http://partsdr.com/part/wp74007336-insulation/?gclid=CJyy8sKUkNICFYFofgoddYcORA).

Answer (score 1):

No. Manufacturers don't spend money doing things like installing insulation if they're not important.

This is especially true where you have tenants who are less concerned with careful use of the appliances than you'd be, and where you are potentially liable for injury or death.

If by "my rental house" you actually meant "the house I rent", you'd need permission from the owner (but don't expect to get it, for the reasons I mentioned).

Comment: +1000. On either side of the equation (renter/rentee), you would be legally responsible for potential massive damages.